# How do I submit a JSON to SOLR using Zend_Client?

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, curl, solr

How do I submit a JSON to SOLR using Zend_Client?

Assume the JSON I am using is (It was taken from the SOLR WIKI, so I assume it is right).

```
$JSON ='[{"id" : "3", "title" : "test3","description":"toottoto totot ototot "}]';
```

I see no error in the solr error log, this is the code I use to submit
DOES NOT WORK

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json';
$Client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
$Client->resetParameters();
$Client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
$Client->setHeaders('Content-type','application/json');
$Client->setParameterPost($JSON);//***** WRONG *****
    $Client->setRawData($JSON); //* **** RIGHT FROM ANSWER BELOW, STILL NEED TO ENCODE IT!
$response = $Client->request();
```

THIS WORKS FROM THE COMMAND LINE!

```
sudo curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[{"id" : "3", "title" : "test3","description":"toottoto totot ototot "}]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setParameterPost()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Http_Client.html#%5CZend_Http_Client%3a%3asetParameterPost%28%29) method takes two arguments, the parameter name and its value like this:

`$client->setParameterPost('name', 'john');  // results in name=john`

Try using [setRawData()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Http_Client.html#%5CZend_Http_Client%3a%3asetRawData%28%29) instead, this will let you set raw post data.

Comment: Tried it both ways in the setParameterPost. Do I need to encode the JSON string first?

Comment: You don't want to use setParameterPost, but instead use setRawData() since you aren't sending name/value pair post data, but rather a single JSON string.  You will want to urlencode your JSON string when you pass it to setRawData since it doesn't do any encoding.

Comment: You might want to put/contribute that answer to some official document.

Comment: They do show that [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html#zend.http.client.raw_post_data) on the advanced Zend_Http_Client usage page, but did you have thoughts on somewhere else to post it?  I agree it is a bit hard to find.

Comment: SOLR has tutorial on how to integrate with PHP http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP is the landing page, somewhee in it probably